# Узнать все домены и поддомены на одном ip

Tags: php, ip

Вопрос простой, но не могу найти решение, которые выдаст мне все домены на одном айпи. И потом все поддомены.

К примеру, есть айпи `45.55.63.13`. Как узнать при помощи php все домены, которые есть на данном айпи и потом к каждому домену все поддомены?

И второй вопрос, если сгенерировать все возможные айпи адреса, применить к ним свой скрипт, то по логике я получу внушительный список сайтов?

Comment: Это технически невозможно

Comment: bing.com умеет искать сайты по ip, для этого в строке запроса передают "ip:45.55.63.13". но он поисковик, он показывает только то, что индексировал. А в индекс никогда все не попадает. по указанному вами ip ничего нет. И он дает только сайты, не домены. Информация по доменам на ip нигде не хранится и получить ее не возможно.

Comment: А ip v4 элементарно генерятся, просто перебираете все числа от 1 до 4294967295 преобразуете их в ip. выбрасываете частные и мультикаст диапазоны

Comment: @Mike IPv6 . :)

Comment: Ну как бы есть много сайтов где по IP я могу посмотреть все сайты которые там лежат. Как они тогда делают?

Comment: Вы не можете посмотреть все сайты. Вы можете видеть на них только часть сайтов. Они обращаются к поисковикам с подобными запросами, как я показал на примере bing. Единственный способ собрать такую информацию это брать все возможные имена сайтов и по ним получать их ip и складывать в БД, чем и занимаются поисковые системы. И по этой причине вы никогда нигде не найдете внутренние домены на ip, которые ни когда не светились в интернете, потому что поисковики про них не знают